# unittest for opening and reading url

Tags: python, mocking, urllib

I am writting unittests and I am not able to understand how can I write unittest for reading a url.

```
def testing():
  main_ip = "localhost"
  another_url = "http://localhost:8086/test"

  try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(another_url)
    body = response.read()
    if body:
      main_ip = body.split(':')[0]
  except urllib2.URLError as urlerr:
    pass

  return main_ip
```

I do not understand how can I mock or write unittest for urlopen and read?

Comment: No. Its very simple and basic example & diff from that question. Can you explain me how to work on this?

Comment: The duplicate seems pertinent to me. If you disagree, please [edit] your question to clarify why the answers in the duplicate are not suitable for your scenario.